Convert Hex to Image in C#
I have this hex data, 0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600..., I have that in a string, in the xaml of my WPF app I have an <Image/> where this encoded image needs to end up with. I have several questions about this.

The biggest problem, I just cannot find a way to decode it, I do not understand how it works either, I just know that I have a string and I need to end up with an image, I do not know if that image needs to be saved somewhere, or that I can directly add the image to the <Image/> in the actual script... I need help with this, I'd just like a method where I can give the string with it and it returns an image I can use.

What is the best way to do it? Like for example if it is a profile picture on different pages, should I save it somewhere in a way or have the string somewhere and decode it the whole time or?..


Note: The hex data is right, I used this website with this input + output: click to see my test

You can convert hex string to byte array, then make BitmapImage from byte array, then set that bitmapimage as source for you Image control.
